# Two way data binding not working in bootstrap model

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 radio button on model. First time i am opening model that time 2 way data binding working fine. If i am redirect another route and come again on model then 2 way data binding not working.

**model.html**:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="disclaimerEvent"
           ng-model="disclaimerEvent.selectedevent"
           value="GETANY" required="required">
    Continue for the current plan year.
</label>
```

**model.js**:

```
$scope.disclaimerEvent = {'selectedevent':''};
```

Comment: can u try using $apply();

Comment: What error you get on console?

Comment: I am using $apply(). But no change on view.And on console i can see value changed.But in view that is not reflect.